# Wrapping an Expression Tree with a Logger

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm doing some work in Expression Trees.  When you call ToString() on an Expression Tree, you get a lovely bit of diagnostic text (here is a sampling):

```
 ((Param_0.Customer.LastName == "Doe") 
     AndAlso ((Param_0.Customer.FirstName == "John") 
     Or (Param_0.Customer.FirstName == "Jane")))
```

So I wrote this bit of code, in an attempt to wrap the Expression with some logging capability:

```
public Expression WithLog(Expression exp)
{
    return Expression.Block(exp, Expression.Call(
        typeof (Debug).GetMethod("Print",
            new Type [] { typeof(string) }),
        new [] { exp } ));
}
```

I half-expected the method call to infer the ToString() usage, but I suppose that's a compile-time feature.  When I execute this, I get the error:

> Expression of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.String' of method 'Void Print(System.String)

Fair enough.  But when I change it to this:

```
public Expression WithLog(Expression exp)
{
    return Expression.Block(exp, Expression.Call(
        typeof (Debug).GetMethod("Print",
            new Type [] { typeof(string) }),
        new [] { exp.ToString() } ));
}
```

It doesn't compile.  Why?  And what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't compile because it's expecting an array of `Expression`s, but you're giving it an array of strings. You'd need to change it to an expression which calls `ToString` on `Expression.Constant(exp)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, it's expecting `Expression[]`, but you've passed it `string[]`. You can do this, which will immediately run `ToString()` on `exp`:

```
public Expression WithLog(Expression exp)
{
    return Expression.Block(Expression.Call(
        typeof (Debug).GetMethod("Print",
            new Type [] { typeof(string) }),
        new [] { Expression.Constant(exp.ToString()) } ), exp);
}
```

Which yields:

```
Print("c => ((c.LastName == "Doe") AndAlso ((c.FirstName == "John") OrElse (c.LastName == "Jane")))")
```

Alternatively, you could change `Expression.Constant(exp.ToString())` to be an invocation of `ToString` on `exp`, so that the `ToString` executed when you invoke the expression.

```
public Expression WithLog(Expression exp)
{
    return Expression.Block(Expression.Call(
        typeof (Debug).GetMethod("Print",
            new Type [] { typeof(string) }),
        new [] { Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(exp), exp.GetType().GetMethod("ToString")) } ), exp);
}
```

Which gives:

```
Print(c => ((c.LastName == "Doe") AndAlso ((c.FirstName == "John") OrElse (c.LastName == "Jane"))).ToString())
```

Comment: Apparently some of my assumptions about how this works were invalid, because I'm now getting the error `The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Void' and 'System.Void'` ... But I'm going to mark this completed anyway, since it solved the problem at hand.  Thank you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Glad to have helped. As for your other error, can I assume you're doing something like `Expression.OrElse(WithLog(...), ...)` ? If that *is* the case, you'll need to change the block in the `WithLog` method to return the original expression. As it stands, it's compiling to something like `(e) => Print(exp) || e.LastName = "Doe"`

Comment: More like `WithLog(Expression.OrElse(blah))`.  But yeah, something like that.  And you're right; I think I need to return the original expression, not the new one.  I'm quite new to Expression Trees.

Comment: Ah, it's because the parameters of `Expression.Block` are the wrong way around. It's currently doing nothing with `exp`, executing `Print`, and returning the void result from `Print`. If you change it from `Expression.Block(exp, --printExpression--)` to `Expression.Block(--printExpression--, exp)`, it should work fine